# Unable to set upload_tmp_dir on IIS

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, configuration

So I'm trying to set the `php upload_tmp_dir` setting on an IIS machine.

I changed the setting in `php.ini` but `phpinfo()` still shows the default folder. I checked the permissions of `IIS_IUSRS` who have write, read, modify, etc.

I also ran this to check if the new folder was writable:

```
$filename = 'C:\inetpub\temp\uploads';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo $filename . ' is writable';
} else {
    echo $filename . ' is not writable';
}
```

I changed the `max_file_uploads` value to test if the PHP config being loaded was the most up-to-date, and it was.

What am I missing?

Comment: You may have to restart the service so that `php.ini` will be read again and new info loaded.

Comment: @zipser I checked that by changing the `max_file_upload` value, it was picked up. The `upload_tmp_dir` wasn't?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And it turned out the `php.ini` config file had duplicate entries for `upload_tmp_dir`, the last of which was the default folder`c:\windows\temp`. I commented that setting out and everything is now fine.

This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/128017/php-ignores-upload-tmp-dir) got me to check for that.

Comment: Helped me to fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you look towards the bottom of the file you will find this.

```
[WebPIChanges]
error_log=C:\Windows\temp\PHP54_errors.log
upload_tmp_dir=C:\Windows\temp
session.save_path=C:\Windows\temp
cgi.force_redirect=0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
fastcgi.impersonate=1
fastcgi.logging=0
max_execution_time=300
date.timezone=America/New_York
extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\ext\"
```

Chance the temp directory here too or comment it out.